# exported class has or using name from external module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I update to angular-cli to v22-1 and just want test my http.service

I get this error :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:/Users/e/WebstormProjects/servicyz/src/app/http.service.ts (9,3): Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module "C:/Users/e/WebstormProjects/serv
icyz/node_modules/rxjs/Observable" but cannot be named.)
C:/Users/e/WebstormProjects/servicyz/src/app/http.service.ts (9,3): Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Response' from external module "C:/Users/e/WebstormProjects/servicyz/node_modules/@angular/htt
p/src/static_response" but cannot be named.)
```

Why ? I import my `http.service.ts` inside `app.module.ts` in `providers[]` array; content of my HttpService class is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  getData(){
    return this.http.get("https://example.com/title.json")
  }
}
```

Need I always create ngModule and export my class, then add it inside imports[] in app.module.ts ? Why I can't simply import my service inside providers ? What this mean :

```
Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module "
```

Does it mean I already use Observable in my app.module.ts? Can someone guide me here thanks.

### Update OK:

I juste add Observable return like this `getData():Observable<any>{...}` and all work ! Can someone explain me why this behavior ? Why do I need write this return type ?

Comment: My tought would be that specifying this just added the import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; and it fixed it.

Comment: Do you read my Update ? I find solution but why need mention return type of my function here... this I don't understand I heard it's [typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944) bug and will be fixed   but donno

Comment: Yup, and that's my guess. You were already returing an Observable from Rxjs package which wasn't imported. Adding the return type did not fix the issue, adding the Rxjs import did.

Comment: Yes that I agree; but with IDE like webstorm you only type Observable and import are automatically.... this isn't problem and this I didn't forget no worry, my question is another : why  need specify type return while this worked before but now I explicitly need specify type for my method and asfaik  return type are optional :) .... it's maybe bug see link